# Is there an established pattern for managing resources over websockets?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

When managing resources over HTTP, REST and SOAP have become fairly common ways of maintaining remote resources / consuming APIs.

Does anything like this exist for a WebSocket API yet? Is there a well established style to follow when implementing an API with HTTP WebSockets?

Comment: There are several.  Which you choose depends on what you are trying to do.  https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) - a protocol on top of WebSocket that provides *Remote Procedure Calls* and *Publish & Subscribe*  messaging patterns.

There are [implementations](http://wamp.ws/implementations/) of WAMP in different languages, for example, here is how [JavaScript programming](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/#show-me-some-code) looks like.

Disclaimer: I am original author of WAMP and Autobahn.